# How run the ``rspec --init` for a sub-directory ?`

Tags: ruby, rspec

I'am trying to write a simple ruby code supposed to automate tasks. One of the task is initializing the rspec gem for a directory which is not the current directory.

I made first tries directly in the terminal before writing my code in he ruby file. Here is what I have tried (in a terminal window) :

```
$rspec --init a_sub_directory
```

OR

```
$rspec a_sub_directory --init
```

The result in both cases : all the rspec elements ( .rspec + spec/spec_helper.rb) are created in the current directory and the sub directory did not change its content.

Is there anything possible to get the rspec elements created in a sub directory of the current directory ?

Comment: Can you `cd` into the subdirectory and run the command there?

Answer (score 0):

Use the `Dir.chdir` method to change the current directory and then execute `rspec --init`. It could be :

```
Dir.mkdir("a_sub_directory")
Dir.chdir("a_sub_directory")
system("rspec --init)
```

And that's it; I've tried this, it works.